# Evaluate $\int_0^\frac 12 \frac{x^2}{(n+\frac 12)^2 - x^2} dx$

Tags: integration

I'm asked to evaluate this integral :

$$\int_0^\frac 12 \frac{x^2}{(n+\frac 12)^2 - x^2} dx$$

I guess a substitution could help ? I'm sure the solution is not so hard but it's been too long since I've done real math so I'm a bit lost. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{x^2}{(n+\frac{1}{2})^2 - x^2} = \frac{(n + \frac{1}{2})^2}{(n+\frac{1}{2})^2 - x^2} - \frac{(n+\frac{1}{2})^2 - x^2}{(n+\frac{1}{2})^2 - x^2} = \frac{(n + \frac{1}{2})^2}{(n+\frac{1}{2})^2 - x^2} - 1$$

Comment: @anon Damn I'm very rusty. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{1}{2} } \frac{x^2}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-x^2} d x 
= & \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left[\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-x^2\right]}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-x^2} d x \\
= & \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{d x}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-x^2}-\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} 1 d x \\
= & \frac{2n+1}{4} \int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\left[\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}-x}+\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}+x}\right] d x-\frac{1}{2} \\
= & \frac{2n+1}{4}\left[\ln \left|\frac{n+\frac{1}{2}+x}{n+\frac{1}{2}-x }\right|\right]_0^{\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{2} \\
= & \frac{2n+1}{4} \ln \left|1+\frac{1}{n}\right|-\frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: thanks for the answer but you've missed $(n+\frac 12)^2$ at the second line

Comment: Thank you for catching it, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Set $a = \frac{1}{2}\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and substitute $x=2au$ hence the integral becomes

$$
\begin{split}
\int_{0}^{a} \frac{4a^{2}u^{2}}{4a^{2}-4a^{2}u^{2}}2adu & = 2a\int_{0}^{a}\frac{u^{2}}{1-u^{2}}du 
\\ & = 2a\left(-a+\int_{0}^{a}\frac{du}{1-u^{2}}\right)
\end{split}
$$

Now you can solve it with partial fractions.